# Infinite loop when logging out using custom login form

Tags: php, redirect, login, wp-login-form

I have a child theme that I'm using based on a parent theme I created. The parent theme uses the standard `wp_login_form` while this child theme uses a username only option (the site itself is local - not internet facing - and is IP locked).

Essentially I have a login form that you select the user from the dropdown and then submit which checks some validations to authenticate. If I clear the browser cache and cookies and go to the site I see the form. I can log in, and then use the site no problem. When I log out, it goes to my custom logout page but then loops between `home_url` and `home_url('/login/`)`

It hasn't caused any issues on any of the other sites in the network (multisite), but if I revert the login to the parent theme page there is no loop.

I was wondering if I was missing something in the code - or if there was another builtin way of logging in without a "password" and just a drop down?

[image]

---

## **Code**

**login.php**

```php
// build the form
$mb_login_args = [
    'role__not_in'  => [ 'site_owner', 'viewer_user', 'administrator' ]
];

// get the users
$mb_users = get_users( $mb_login_args );

echo '<form id="mbform" method="post">';
    echo '<p class="login-username">';
        echo '<label for="mb_login_username">Select resource</label>';
        echo '<select name="log" id="mb_login_username">';
                echo '<option value="">Select a room</option>';
                // loop users
                foreach( $mb_users as $mb_user ) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $mb_user->user_login . '">' . $mb_user->display_name . '</option>';
                }
        echo '</select>';
    echo '</p>';

    echo '<p class="login-submit">';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="mb_login_submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save resource">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="pwd" value="{mb_login_password}">';
        wp_nonce_field( 'mb_action_login', 'mb_field_login' );
    echo '</p>';
echo '</form>';
```

**functions.php**

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if( is_page('login') && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        include_once locate_template( '/_mbcore/validation-room.php' );
    }
});
```

**validation-room.php**

```php
$mb_field_room  = ( isset( $_POST[ 'mb_field_login' ] ) ? $_POST['mb_field_login'] : null );
if( $mb_field_room || wp_verify_nonce( $mb_field_room, 'mb_action_login' ) || !empty($mb_field_room) ) {
    $mb_meeting_log = isset($_POST['log'])  ? $_POST['log'] : null;
    $mb_meeting_pwd = isset($_POST['pwd']) && $_POST['pwd'] == '{mb_login_password}' ? 'password' : null;
// other validation here
    // on success
    wp_set_auth_cookie( get_user_by('login', $mb_meeting_log)->ID, true, true );
}
```

**logout.php**

```php
// do some checking here for $_GET['mblock'] and if valid number
// then in a switch statement 

    case 88:
        // log out the user
        wp_logout();

        // set the user ID to 0
        wp_set_current_user(0);

        // redirect user
        // $wp_logout_url = home_url('wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=' . wp_create_nonce('log-out') );
        wp_safe_redirect( $wp_logout_url );
        break;
```

**parent theme: functions.php**

```php
function mb_page_redirects() {

    // authenticated users
    if( is_user_logged_in() )  {

        // setup: incomplete
        if( get_option('mb_theme_setup') === 'true' ) {

            // direct the valid user
            // mb_is_admin() checks custom caps
            if( mb_is_admin() ) {

                if( !is_page('setup') ) {
                    wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/admin/setup/') );
                    exit;
                }

            // otherwise log the user out
            } else {
                wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/admin/logout/') );
                exit;
            }

        // setup: complete
        } else {

            if( mb_is_admin() ) {

                // send admin to the config panel
                if( is_page( array('login', 'pw', 'setup') ) ) {
                    wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/admin/') );
                    exit;
                }

            // non-administrator redirects
            } else {

                // send admin to the front
                if( is_page( array('admin', 'setup', 'login', 'pw') ) ) {
                    wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }

    // non-authenticated users
    } else {

        // check the setting for authentication bypass
        // empty or false means we need to log in
        if( get_option('mb_setting_auth_bypass') == 'true' ) {

            if( is_page( array('login', 'pw') ) ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
                exit;
            }

        } else {

            // force users to the login screen
            if( !is_page('login') ) {
                wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/admin/login/') );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `mb_page_redirects` in your request workflow? Also at what point and where are you arriving in `logout.php`?

Comment: @Adam from a plug-in i made that applies to all the themes. they all use the same structure: login, logout, admin, front, password, taxonomy, setup

Comment: I'm trying to work out your auth workflow, not sure I've grokked it yet but in your `template_redirect` callback you include `validation-room.php` which then tries to validate the request, but after doing so, you don't `exit;` to kill the request which means the request falls through to the page you're posting to (as you are neither doing a redirect) this may keep the user on the same URI (path) which gets processed future in `mb_page_redirects` and your logic may be interpreting the condition incorrectly.

Comment: @Adam i knew i forgot something! so the form is called via ajax and then it has a die at the end when successfully set. if you see that gif the banner goes green

Comment: Ok cool, so did that solve the issue for you or is that only an additional detail?

Comment: @Adam additional information sorry. i tried to remove as much unrelated code as it was already lengthy

Comment: When and how is `mb_page_redirects` being called? Is that firing on a hook and if so which e.g `init` or `logout_redirect` or `login_redirect` etc? How do you end up in `logout.php` and where are you rewriting URLs as that file passes `$wp_logout_url =  home_url('wp-login.php?action=logout...etc)` to `wp_safe_redirect` that doesn't correspond to `/admin/logout` in the gif. By the way make sure you `exit;` after that redirect too in `logout.php`

Comment: @Adam the `mb_page_redirects` is called via `add_action( 'template_redirect', 'mb_page_redirects' );` in the mu-plugin that I wrote for all sites. then there is the `functions.php` code above within the child theme. `mb_page_redirects` is called every time. `logout.php` is via the `mb_page_redirects` code which in the url: `domain.ltd/admin/logout/?mblock=88` and that triggers the switch statement to run the `logout.php` code

Comment: Did you place an `exit;` after the redirect in logout.php before the `break;` statement in the switch?

Comment: @Adam I did but still didn’t fix the issue. i’m still debugging but the only difference is the way the authentication occurs. not passing it through the wp-login opposed to just setting the cookie

Comment: I've added an answer below. Short of posting all your code on say a Gist on GitHub I can only recommend (if the answer does not help) to then focus your efforts on debugging the conditional logic in `mb_page_redirects` by placing log statements in the appropriate conditional clauses and inspecting your log file to see where you are ending up during the login-logout process. This should give you an idea of which conditional(s) is/are potentially failing. Remember though, if `wp_set_current_user` is not set correctly to begin with it could lead your debug efforts down a stray path.

Answer (score 0):

I am speculating here after reviewing your logic/comments above, yet let's try as follows

**Possible issue:**

During login, although you are setting the auth cookie, you are not setting the current user and this is potentially the cause of the break-down upon logout due to `is_user_logged_in` returning a false-positive/negative result.

**Possible resolution:**

In your `validation-room.php` add a call to `wp_set_current_user`, as when entering your callback `mb_page_redirects` on the `template_redirect` hook, you are relying on `is_user_logged_in` to function correctly, which itself checks the state of the `global $current_user` variable.

Under the hood `is_user_logged_in` calls `wp_get_current_user` which calls `_wp_get_current_user` which fires a filter `determine_current_user` that calls two internal callbacks `wp_validate_auth_cookie` and `wp_validate_logged_in_cookie`.

It is possible that the initial improper validation and later subsequent calls to `wp_logout` and `wp_set_current_user` are somehow causing an issue.

```php
$mb_field_room  = ( isset( $_POST[ 'mb_field_login' ] ) ? $_POST['mb_field_login'] : null );

if( $mb_field_room || wp_verify_nonce( $mb_field_room, 'mb_action_login' ) || !empty($mb_field_room) ) {
    $mb_meeting_log = isset($_POST['log'])  ? $_POST['log'] : null;
    $mb_meeting_pwd = isset($_POST['pwd']) && $_POST['pwd'] == '{mb_login_password}' ? 'password' : null;

    $user = get_user_by('login', $mb_meeting_log);

    wp_clear_auth_cookie(); // let's be sure about it...
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true, true );
    wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );
}
```

Comment: as hopeful as I was it didn't resolve it. I think you are on the right track though, as if I log into the site and then log out (into the loop) it doesn't trash the cookies/authentication from other sites unlike when logging in it allows access to all of them